# How to tell if a layer is Z-aware or M-aware

Tags: arcpy, coordinates, geoprocessing, 3d

I am trying to detect if a layer is Z-aware or M-aware. If it is, I need to flag it to be reconfigured without Z/M-awareness.

In the example below, I have already pulled down the layers and am checking them individually for correct configuration. After researching the ArcPy pages for awhile, the closest thing I could find was to check if the layer had a [VCS](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/classes/vcs.htm) (Vertical Coordinate System) through the [spatialReference](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/classes/spatialreference.htm) class.

```py
import arcpy

# Start mapping table
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapDoc, "Layers")[0]
layerList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapDoc, "", df)
for layer in layerList:
    types, flag = getLayerTypes(layer)
    # Program continues from here but is not important to the question.

def getLayerTypes(layer):
    types = []
    status = 'Good'
    desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
    if hasattr(desc, "spatialReference") and hasattr(desc.spatialReference, "VCS") and desc.spatialReference.VCS is not None:
            types.append('Vertical Coordinate System Enabled')
            status = 'Critical'
    # There are more checks here but it is not important to the question...
    return types, status
```

Is there a more accurate way to detect these values? Currently, I am only assuming that if VCS is enabled then Z/M-awareness is also enabled. I would like to have a method that provides 100% certainty.

Comment: A VCS is ***not*** required for coordinate Z/M awareness.  Look at the `SpatialReference` properties `hasMPrecision` / `hasZPrecision` instead.

Comment: Thank you a ton! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler approach is in the following code I provide, it checks if the layer is a vector dataset then checks the properties of the layer using the Describe Object:

```py
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
lstLayers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df)
for lyr in lstLayers:
    if lyr.isFeatureLayer:
        # lyr is a vector dataset so not a raster or group layer
        desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
        if desc.hasZ:
            print(lyr.name +  " is Z aware")
        elif desc.hasM:
            print(lyr.name + " is M aware")
        else:
            print(lyr.name + " is neither Z or M aware")
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the help. Are only feature layers capable of being M/Z-aware?

Comment: Yes only vector data can hold x/y/z/m values.